# Pass parameters to function call in event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have this

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').keyup(function() {
    var prop = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var val = jQuery(this).val();

    stuff;
}
```

and

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').click(function() {
    var prop = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var val = jQuery(this).val();

    stuff;
}
```

two functions are the same, so I'd like to simplify it by defining external function and calling it with

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').click('myFunction');
```

but how would I pass parameters to myFunction?

```
function myFunction(element) {
    stuff;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can combine both your handlers into one:

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').on('click keyup', function() {
    var prop = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    // stuff;
});
```

Or for older versions of jQuery:

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').bind('click keyup', function() { // ... });
```

Secondly, jQuery will automatically apply the current element to any function you provide, so the `this` keyword will still be the element raising the event when you do this:

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').on('click keyup', myHandler);

function myHandler() {
    var prop = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    // stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of those quotes...

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').click(myFunction);
```

Comment: and how to pass two parameters to this function?

Comment: If you have more than 1 function, then simply write anonymous function and call them inside... `.click(function () { myFunction1(); myFunction2(); });`

Answer (score 0):

In the context of `MyFunction` `this` is your clicked element. Additionally, the `click` handler takes 1 argument, so your function signature should be `function MyFucntion(event)` where the event argument holds data about the action (e.g. `event.target` is the clicked element).

so this is how you would define your handler:

```
function myFunction(event){
    var element = event.target;
    // Note: event.target == this
    //do stuff
}
```

and this is how you would bind it to the event:

```
$(".widget-prop").click(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.on` function instead of the shortcut `.click` and pass all required events as paramter:

```
jQuery('.widget-prop').on('click keyup', function() {
  var prop = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  var val = jQuery(this).val();
  //stuff;
});
```

EDIT: deprecated => shortcut

Comment: Who said that `click()` is deprecated?

Comment: You're right, it's not deprecated but a shortcut function. Sorry, my fault.